# SumIf VBA выдает ошибку

Tags: excel, vba

хотел для себя автоматизировать рутину.
Есть 2 таблицы:
[image: рис1]

Хотелось бы добавить данные из Таблицы Б в Таблицу А  с sumif vba
Написал примитивный код:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Оба таблицы на Лист1.

Comment: `Range("M3:M6")` и `Range(N3:N6)`. А вообще, задачу нужно полнее описывать.

Answer (score 0):

почему бы просто не использовать ВПР? (=ВПР(A3;$F$2:$G$6;2;0))
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *ВПР* выберет данные только одной строки, *СУММЕСЛИ* просуммирует данные всех строк указанного клиента